# Umbraco:create childnodes in content using C#

Tags: c#, umbraco

I am working with umbraco 6.1.6. I want to know how to add a node into the content tree programmatically?

This is the structure I want:

content

- Home

  - start
  - calender
  - frontpage sliders
  - fotos
  - news

Here childnodes have the same document types. How can I create these childnodes programatically using C#?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this,

```
using umbraco.cms.businesslogic.web;

DocumentType dt = DocumentType.GetByAlias("alias");

// The umbraco user that should create the document, 
// 0 is the umbraco system user, and always exists
umbraco.BusinessLogic.User u = new umbraco.BusinessLogic.User(0);

//Replace 1055 with id of parent node
Document doc = Document.MakeNew("new child node name", dt, u, 1055);

//after creating the document, prepare it for publishing 
doc.Publish(u);

//Tell umbraco to publish the document
umbraco.library.UpdateDocumentCache(doc.Id);
```

OR

```
using Umbraco.Core;
using Umbraco.Core.Models;
using Umbraco.Core.Services;

// Get the Umbraco Content Service
var contentService = Services.ContentService;
var product = contentService.CreateContent(
    "my new presentation", // the name of the product
    1055, // the parent id should be the id of the group node 
    "Presentation", // the alias of the product Document Type
    0);

// We need to update properties (product id, original name and the price)
product.SetValue("title", "My new presentation");

// finally we need to save and publish it (which also saves the product!)
// - that's done via the Content Service
contentService.SaveAndPublish(product);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Just for information: how can I get the ID of a content I've just creaerd? There are no overload for SaveAndPublish method which return any Id

Comment: @Ras ContentService.CreateContent returns an IContent instance and it has a property called Id which points to your newly created content's Id.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Umbraco's API for that. This is all covered in the Umbraco documentation here: http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/

In a nutshell, you can use the `CreateContent()` method of the API's `ApplicationContext.Current.Services.ContentService`.